# Libgdx opengl error

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I started a new project with libgdx on **android studio** but when i run the program i see that:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: OpenGL 2.0 or higher with the FBO extension is required. OpenGL version: 1.1.0
Type: OpenGL
```

But when i use GPU Caps Viewer i see that :

```
GL_RENDERER Intel HD Graphics 3000
Gl_Version:3.1.0-Build 9.17.10.4459
GLSL 1.40-Intel Build 9.17.10.4459
```

I tried to change `import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20; to import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL30;` but still not working.

Comment: It seems that your version is not 2.0 but 1.1. I also see you have an Intel graphics card. Maybe its the same case as: https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/issues/119 ? Can be that windows 10 doesnt support your GPU/Driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try configuring the LWJGL backend to allow software-emulated OpenGL:

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.allowSoftwareOpenGL", "true");
```

Comment: I tried, but nothing change, i will change my pc... Thank you guys